# PHP header() not redirecting even with output disabled

Tags: php, ajax

I have a button which I want to call a php script which does some stuff followed by a redirect to a new page based on that stuff. Relevant Code is:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="newTourney()">New Tournament</button><br>
```

and

```
<script>
    function newTourney(){
        var name = prompt("Tournament Name:");
        $.ajax({
          url: "new_tournament.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {name: name}
        });
    }
</script>
```

new_tournament.php (including ob_...() and error reporting enabled to try to fix this):

```
<?php
use general\orm\UsbgfGenOrm;
use trn\interfaces\Usbgf\UsbgfUtil;
use trn\orm\DimEvent;
use trn\orm\DimTournament;
include_once __DIR__ . "\..\usbgf_bootstrap.php";

ob_start();

$club = UsbgfUtil::getOnlineCircuitClub();
$tournament = new DimTournament($club);
$event = new DimEvent($tournament);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    $tournament->Name = $_POST["name"];
    $event->Name = $_POST["name"];
}

$tourneyId = $tournament->getId();

ob_end_clean();

header("Location: edit_tourney.php?id=" . $tourneyId);
exit;
```

It simply isn't doing anything whatsoever when the button is pressed. I've tried printing the response from the ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "new_tournament.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {name: name},
      complete: function(response){
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

When I do this, it prints the entire html from the page I'm trying to redirect to (and any other echos) to the console, so its definitely accessing the correct files at least.

My best guess is that something about `$.ajax` doesn't allow for redirects or something like that? I'm not sure what to replace it with but I use a similar ajax call elsewhere to a script without a redirect and it works just fine.

Comment: Redirecting an AJAX request has no bearing on the active browser page.

Comment: The redirect is just telling `$.ajax` to get its response from the other URL, it doesn't change the page the browser is displaying.

Comment: Why are you using AJAX in the first place if you want to reload the page?

Comment: Using ajax because I am still learning and didn't know better.
So what is the best way to do that then? Chrome dev tools is showing that there is a get request being made to that second .php file so I'm not sure whether to change the request type to a `$.get` or the like or to do something in the ajax complete callback